# How can I resolve the transition so that it remains relative behaviour in routing animation?

Tags: css, angular, angular-animations

It currently works so that each submodule contains the following:

```
<div class="animation_container">
    <!-- any content -->

    <footer>...</footer> <!-- currently here -->
</div>
```

```css
.animation_container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

So, all first submodules are absolute, so they can fade to each other. But! If I would like a common footer, it will be put on top of the browser. I understand why, so my temporary solution is to put all submodules bottom.

**Question**: How can I modify this code than  I can move `<footer>` to app.component.html from all submodules?

**app.component.html**

```
<div [@routeAnimations]="getRouteAnimationData(routeOutlet)">
    <router-outlet #routeOutlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>

<!-- I would like to move my footer -->
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    animations: [
        trigger('routeAnimations', [
            transition('* => *', [
                style({ position: 'relative' }),
                group([
                    query(':enter', [
                        style({ opacity: 0 }),
                    ], { optional: true }),
                    query(':leave', [
                        style({ opacity: 1 }),
                    ], { optional: true }),
                ]),
                group([
                    query(':enter', [
                        animate('0.3s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
                    ], { optional: true }),
                    query(':leave', [
                        animate('0.3s', style({ opacity: 0 }))
                    ], { optional: true }),
                ]),
            ]),
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(
        private _elementRef: ElementRef,
    ) {
    }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._elementRef.nativeElement.removeAttribute("ng-version");
    }
    
    getRouteAnimationData(routeOutlet: RouterOutlet) {
        return routeOutlet.activatedRouteData['animation'] ?? "HomeModule"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your animation_container hat position absolute and not top / bottom.
In case you realy need "absolute", set in app.component.html a position: 'relative' wrapping div around yout sub component *and* your footer.

Set a aqurate accurate height to the child-component wrapper or a padding or a absolute positon + bottom: 0 to your footer component.

It depends on your requirement.
Mby you can avoid position absolute? If not, here is an example.

```css
.animation_container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative; 
    height: 90vh;
}

.wrapper > footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class="animation_container">
    <span>Content...</span>

    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>

<footer>Footer NEW</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a solution for me. On the one hand, the content can be of any height. On the other hand, you just put the footer away out by one level in the same module. The point is to have the footer there regardless of navigation (i.e. submodule).

Comment: You can add overflow: scroll to the content in case you need a sticky footer. Or using a grid layout. My snipped is not a final solution. Its just an example how to move the Footer away. The content span woule be your router outlet